# How to make a second loop with exclude function in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

*single.php* has two loops, one to show selected post and the other to show all other posts.
Now I want to exclude the post returned from the first loop.

I found this snippet `<?php query_posts(array('post__not_in' => array($thePostID))); ?>`

I don't know how to incorporate that into my code or if there is another way to solve this

here my *single.php* code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


     <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the post data so we can run another query ?>

 <?php 

 $args_second = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

 // The Second Query
 $second_query = new WP_Query( $args_second );

 // The Loop
 if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
        $second_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original Post ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code in place of your single.php code.
Test it.

> ```
> <?php get_header(); ?>
> <div id="primary" class="site-content">
>     <div id="content" role="main">
>
> <?php 
>  $firstPosts = array();
> while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
>
> $postid = get_the_ID();
> $firstPosts[] = $postid;
>      <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
>         <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
>         <?php the_content(); ?>
>     </div>
>
>             <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
>
>         <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
>
>     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the post data so we can run another query ?>
>
>  <?php 
>
>  //$args_second = array(
>    //     'posts_per_page' => -1,
>    // );
>
>  // The Second Query
>
>  $second_query = new WP_Query( array('post__not_in' => $firstPosts, 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ));
>
>  // The Loop
>  if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
>     while ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
>         $second_query->the_post(); ?>
>
>     <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
>         <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
>         <?php the_content(); ?>
>     </div>
>
>         <?php endwhile; ?>
>         <?php endif; ?>
>     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore original Post ?>
>
>     </div><!-- #content -->
> </div><!-- #primary -->
> ```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. I have added php tags around line 7 and 8 but that results in a blank page

Comment: Please check have you get all the post id of first loop in $firstPosts variable array.